# Django retrieve results by date operation query

Tags: sql, django

I have one model to make my Catalog like this

```py
class Product(models.Model):
    item = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    unit = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    expiration= models.IntegerField(default=365) # Days after admission
    expiration_warning= models.IntegerField(default=30) # Days before expiration
    ...
```

and I have my Inventory like this:

```py
class Inventory(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    quantity= models.DecimalField(default=0, decimal_places=2, max_digits=10)
    admission = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    ...
```

Now **I want to retrieve all Inventory objects that its expiration date is upcoming or has been reached**. 
With a RAW SQL query, it will be something like:

```sql
SELECT product,quantity,admission,expiration,expiration_warning 
FROM Inventory as I JOIN Product as P on I.product=P.id 
WHERE DATEADD(day,(expiration_warning*-1),DATEADD(day,expiration,admission))<=GETDATE()
```

I haven't tried this query yet, it is just an example

I want to achieve this using Django query syntax, can you help me please?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this can achieve what you need:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

expiring_inventory = []
expired_inventory = []
for inventory in Inventory.objects.select_related('product').all(): # 1 query
    p = inventory.product

    expire_datetime = inventory.admission + timedelta(days=p.expiration)
    expiring_datetime = expire_datetime - timedelta(days=p.expiration_warning)

    if expiring_datetime <= datetime.now() < expire_datetime: # not quite expired
        expiring_inventory.append(inventory)
    if expire_datetime <= datetime.now(): # expired
        expired_inventory.append(inventory)
```

You can read more about [Query Sets](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/querysets/) in the django docs.

Comment: I think this should do the trick but it is doing the whole operations in python, and the goal is to make the Database works with a Django Query Syntax because it is faster, any idea? Thank you